What are the `estimates` returned by `avg_slopes()` in modelsummary?
I have an interpretation question of R's marginaleffects avg_slopes function for logistic regression models. Consider the following:
data("mtcars")
library(marginaleffects)
mtcars
mod1<-glm(vs~am+gear+carb, data=mtcars, family="binomial")
summary(mod1)
library(marginaleffects)
avg_slopes(mod1, variables="am")


Is the value of estimate returned by avg_slopes() the change in predicted probability of being a vs (whatever that is). It is not the coefficient, I see that, And it is not the predicted probability. That values is returned in predicted. So the only thing I think it could be is the change in predicted probability, i.e. the effect. Am I wrong?

Because am is a binary (0/1) variable, avg_slopes() computes the difference between the average adjusted predictions udner each level of am. Below is how you would compute this quantity manually:
> mean0 <- mean(predict(mod1, newdata = transform(mtcars, am = 0), type = "response"))
> mean1 <- mean(predict(mod1, newdata = transform(mtcars, am = 1), type = "response"))
> mean1 - mean0
[1] -0.2489939

That is, first it computes the predicted value of the outcomes after setting all units' value of am to 0, then takes the mean of those predicted values and calls that mean(0). Then it does the same, setting am to 1 for all units, and calls the resulting mean mean(1). What is reported is the difference between these means.
avg_slopes() is best used for continuous predictors, in which case the average marginal effect is computed. For binary and categorical predictors, avg_slopes() does the same as avg_comparisons().
